# 403 forbidden when www. before url

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a dedicated server running centos 5.5. I have been messing around with a virtual website via webmin and I think the apache settings messed up some how. When i type in the url without the www. it works fine but if I enter www. it goes to 403 error page

Comment: Do you have a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` on a block that specifies one name (site.com) but not the other (www.site.com)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like apache loads your default vhost (in case it doesn't find the requested ServerName). Check the configuration files yourself for missing ServerAlias.
You can also add CNAME record if you own the domain zone.